# Java wait for Timer thread to complete

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new in Java multithreading, i just implemented Timer class to execute method on specific interval time.

here my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 3000);

    //execute this code after timer finished
    System.out.println("finish");
}

private static class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("inside timer");
    }

}
```

but the output like this :

```
finish
inside timer
```

I want it like this :

```
inside timer
finish
```

so how to wait timer thread to complete and then continue execute code in main thread? any suggestion?

Comment: Don't use a Timer if you do want background threading. Instead simply call `Thread.sleep(...)`. Otherwise if you still want to do background threading, then call `"finish"` **inside** the Timer or in a callback triggered by the Timer.

Comment: Use a `CountLatch` or some other type of `Semaphore` or `Object` monitor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is somewhat vague and may be better answered via [Java's Concurrency Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html), however...

## You could...

Use a "monitor lock"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object lock = new Object();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(lock), 3000);

    synchronized (lock) {
        try {
            lock.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }

    //execute this code after timer finished
    System.out.println("finish");
}

private static class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    private Object lock;

    public MyTimerTask(Object lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("inside timer");
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

}
```

## You could...

Use a `CountDownLatch`...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(cdl), 3000);

    try {
        cdl.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }

    //execute this code after timer finished
    System.out.println("finish");
}

private static class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    private CountDownLatch latch;

    public MyTimerTask(CountDownLatch lock) {
        this.latch = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("inside timer");
        latch.countDown();
    }

}
```

## You could...

Use a callback or simply call a method from the `Timer` class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(new TimerDone() {
        @Override
        public void timerDone() {
            //execute this code after timer finished
            System.out.println("finish");
        }
    }), 3000);
}

public static interface TimerDone {
    public void timerDone();
}

private static class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    private TimerDone done;

    public MyTimerTask(TimerDone done) {
        this.done = done;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("inside timer");            
        done.timerDone();
    }

}
```